# R - Dataframe (group_by/aggregate/pivot_wider) Manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I'm currently having an issue manipulating/aggregating my dataframe. The current data frame I have is as follow:

| Farm | Year | Cow | Duck | Chicken | Sheep | Horse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Farm 1 | 2020 | 22 | 12 | 100 | 30 | 25 |
| Farm 1 | 2020 | 0 | 12 | 120 | 20 | 20 |
| Farm 1 | 2019 | 16 | 6 | 80 | 10 | 16 |
| Farm 1 | 2019 | 12 | 0 | 50 | 0 | 11 |
| Farm 1 | 2018 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 0 |
| Farm 1 | 2018 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 13 | 12 |
| Farm 2 | 2020 | 31 | 28 | 27 | 10 | 14 |
| Farm 2 | 2020 | 0 | 13 | 31 | 20 | 0 |
| Farm 2 | 2019 | 3 | 31 | 0 | 20 | 43 |
| Farm 2 | 2019 | 20 | 50 | 43 | 17 | 42 |
| Farm 2 | 2018 | 39 | 33 | 0 | 48 | 10 |
| Farm 2 | 2018 | 34 | 20 | 28 | 12 | 12 |
| Farm 3 | 2020 | 27 | 0 | 37 | 30 | 42 |
| Farm 3 | 2020 | 50 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Farm 3 | 2019 | 0 | 19 | 0 | 20 | 16 |
| Farm 3 | 2019 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 7 |
| Farm 3 | 2018 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 27 | 0 |
| Farm 3 | 2018 | 0 | 7 | 43 | 49 | 42 |

For simplicity, the code for the data frame is as follows:

```
Farms = c(rep("Farm 1", 6), rep("Farm 2", 6), rep("Farm 3", 6))
Year = rep(c(2020,2020,2019,2019,2018,2018),3)
Cow = c(22,0,16,12,8,0,31,0,3,20,39,34,27,50,0,0,0,0)
Duck = c(12,12,6,0,0,0,28,13,31,50,33,20,0,9,19,2,0,7)
Chicken = c(100,120,80,50,0,10,27,31,0,43,0,28,37,0,0,0,5,43)
Sheep = c(30,20,10,0,16,13,10,20,20,17,48,12,30,0,20,0,27,49)
Horse = c(25,20,16,11,0,12,14,0,43,42,10,12,42,0,16,7,0,42)
Data = data.frame(Farms, Year, Cow, Duck, Chicken, Sheep, Horse)
```

Can I check if anyone knows how I can change the dataframe to the following table below using group_by and/or aggregate and/or pivot_wider or any other ways? The dataframe below aggregated the farm by year and took the average of each animal for the year.

| Farm | Year | Cow | Duck | Chicken | Sheep | Horse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Farm 1 | 2020 | Average of 2020 = (22+0)/2 = 11 | 12 | 110 | 25 | 22.5 |
| Farm 1 | 2019 | 14 | 3 | 65 | 5 | 13.5 |
| Farm 1 | 2018 | 4 | 0 | 5 | 14.5 | 6 |
| Farm 2 | 2020 | 15.5 | 20.5 | 29 | 15 | 7 |
| Farm 2 | 2019 | 11.5 | 40.5 | 21.5 | 18.5 | 42.5 |
| Farm 2 | 2018 | 36.5 | 26.5 | 14 | 30 | 11 |
| Farm 3 | 2020 | 38.5 | 4.5 | 18.5 | 15 | 21 |
| Farm 3 | 2019 | 0 | 10.5 | 0 | 10 | 11.5 |
| Farm 3 | 2018 | 0 | 3.5 | 24 | 38 | 21 |

Thank you in Advance and a happy 2022 to all!

Comment: `aggregate(.~Farms + Year, Data, mean)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aggregate(.~Year + Farms, Data, mean)
  Year  Farms  Cow Duck Chicken Sheep Horse
1 2018 Farm 1  4.0  0.0     5.0  14.5   6.0
2 2019 Farm 1 14.0  3.0    65.0   5.0  13.5
3 2020 Farm 1 11.0 12.0   110.0  25.0  22.5
4 2018 Farm 2 36.5 26.5    14.0  30.0  11.0
5 2019 Farm 2 11.5 40.5    21.5  18.5  42.5
6 2020 Farm 2 15.5 20.5    29.0  15.0   7.0
7 2018 Farm 3  0.0  3.5    24.0  38.0  21.0
8 2019 Farm 3  0.0 10.5     0.0  10.0  11.5
9 2020 Farm 3 38.5  4.5    18.5  15.0  21.0

aggregate(.~Farms + Year, Data, mean)
   Farms Year  Cow Duck Chicken Sheep Horse
1 Farm 1 2018  4.0  0.0     5.0  14.5   6.0
2 Farm 2 2018 36.5 26.5    14.0  30.0  11.0
3 Farm 3 2018  0.0  3.5    24.0  38.0  21.0
4 Farm 1 2019 14.0  3.0    65.0   5.0  13.5
5 Farm 2 2019 11.5 40.5    21.5  18.5  42.5
6 Farm 3 2019  0.0 10.5     0.0  10.0  11.5
7 Farm 1 2020 11.0 12.0   110.0  25.0  22.5
8 Farm 2 2020 15.5 20.5    29.0  15.0   7.0
9 Farm 3 2020 38.5  4.5    18.5  15.0  21.0

Data%>%
   group_by(Farms, Year) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 9 x 7
  Farms   Year   Cow  Duck Chicken Sheep Horse
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Farm 1  2018   4     0       5    14.5   6  
2 Farm 1  2019  14     3      65     5    13.5
3 Farm 1  2020  11    12     110    25    22.5
4 Farm 2  2018  36.5  26.5    14    30    11  
5 Farm 2  2019  11.5  40.5    21.5  18.5  42.5
6 Farm 2  2020  15.5  20.5    29    15     7  
7 Farm 3  2018   0     3.5    24    38    21  
8 Farm 3  2019   0    10.5     0    10    11.5
9 Farm 3  2020  38.5   4.5    18.5  15    21
```

Comment: what is .groups = 'drop' doing here?

Comment: @hachiko it drops the groups. ie `ungroups` the data. If `.groups = 'keep'` then the end table is a grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Onyambu's answer is good. But small thing - and I know you didn't ask for this - you might want to consider if by average you want the mean or median statistic. At first glance, looks like the data might be rather skewed and median might be better for you.

```
Data %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 3:7) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~names)
```

[image]